# Installing gtk2hs failure

Tags: haskell, gtk, cabal-install

I followed the instructions to install `gtk` library on `Windows 8.1 x64` using http://wiki.haskell.org/Gtk2Hs/Installation.

I've installed `MSYS2` and used it to download and build `gtk`. Then I've run:

```
cabal update // ok

cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools // ok

cabal install gtk // failed,
```

`cabal` logs:

- glib.log

  Building glib-0.13.2.2...
  Preprocessing library glib-0.13.2.2...
  dist\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_utils.o:StoreValue_hsc_utils.c:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `__debugbreak'
  dist\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_make.o:StoreValue_hsc_make.c:(.text+0x0): first defined here
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  linking dist\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_make.o failed (exit code 1)
  command was: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\mingw\bin\gcc.exe dist\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_make.o dist\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_utils.o -o dist\build\System\Glib\StoreValue_hsc_make.exe -LC:/msys64/mingw64/lib -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -LC:\Users\Lexa27\AppData\Roaming\cabal\x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.3\utf8-string-1.0.1.1-L8eKHa7Iv9q7FVKUYW6u4b -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\extralibs\text-1.2.1.3 -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\binar_3uXFWMoAGBg0xKP9MHKRwi -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\conta_2C3ZI8RgPO2LBMidXKTvIU -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\bytes_6VWy06pWzJq9evDvK2d4w6 -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\deeps_6vMKxt5sPFR0XsbRWvvq59 -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\array_67iodizgJQIIxYVTp4emlA -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\base_HQfYBxpPvuw8OunzQu6JGM -lwsock32 -luser32 -lshell32 -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\integ_2aU3IZNMF9a7mQ0OzsZ0dS -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib\ghcpr_8TmvWUcS1U1IKHT0levwg3 -LC:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\7.10.3\lib/rts -lm -lwsock32 -lgdi32 -lwinmm
- build.log
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9t961_0P4GbMWhhMklSMDlpRkE/view?usp=sharing
- gtk2hs-buildtools https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9t961_0P4GbdXpGT081V0hHeFE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Did you ensure this `After installing gtk2hs-buildtools, make sure that gtk2hsC2hs is in a directory that is on your %PATH%.`? And please, do not post links with images hosted elsewhere. Try to narrow your problem first and then try to post small logs.

Comment: `gtk2hsC2hs.exe` is in a directory that is on my %PATH%

Comment: The error says "error: ld returned 1 exit status" but then it says "command was: ... gcc.exe". gcc is obviously calling ld, which fails. If you want to know why you'll have to figure out which ld command it is running (you need to pass -v to gcc as well - cabal has a `cc-options` field). Since you are on windows, and a link step is failing, there is 99% chance it is due to one of three things: missing libraries, architecture (x86 v i386) mismatch in one of many possible places, or the `ld` command is simply too long for windows ([8191 chars max](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/830473))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am suffering from the same error message for the last two days and
finally got a work-around (though I am using win7 -x64).

You need to download glib separately from https://hackage.haskell.org/package/glib. Then you need to adjust glib.cabal as described here:
https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2015-October/121935.html
(you have to remove the cpp-option: '-D__attribute__(A)=')

Finally, switch to your glib directory and run:

```
cabal install glib.cabal
```

This should work. You may have to do the same steps with the other gtk+ dependencies.